# Getting unique faces from image data set. opencv/python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, face-detection

I am trying to detect faces from video using opencv haarcascades in python. The face detection works fine for each frame. But if a face is present in multiple frames i'm getting multiple faces of the same person. I now need to get unique faces from my detected faces. Currently I'm trying to us k clustering from opencv on all the data to make clusters and get the unique faces at centers of these clusters. This way I am not getting good results although I get some unique faces.
Can anyone suggest any other way to only get unique faces from my data?

Comment: Interesting CV problem, but need more info. How diverse are the frames? Is it all one shot, one location, with constant lighting? Do the people move around a lot? Have you considered grouping faces that appear in identical or close enough locations in consecutive frames?

Comment: @Junuxx I am doing this in a classroom like environment. Our group is working on an app that marks the students attendance from video captures. The video pans from the front of the room . I.E. Goes left to right. The lightning varies between the frames.mostly the faces are still while capturing but there is motion blur. We couldn't exactly understand the grouping technique hence went for post-processing using clustering.

Comment: You can build a face dataset with the faces you've seen so far. You can then use a [face recognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#gsc.tab=0) to check if you already saw a given face. You can also track the faces, so while a person is in the frame, you can avoid to compare her face to your dataset (and eventually add the new pose of her face to your dataset).

Comment: @Miki Any resource where I can see how to track the faces?

Comment: [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html#gsc.tab=0) for single-target tracking, many examples on google based on OpenCV for multi-target tracking. A simpler approach would be as @Junuxx suggested, i.e. tracking by minimum distance (on some feature, e.g. euclidean distance of centers, or color histogram) detections.